# Hibernate - insert data with one to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am trying to insert data into a `Patient` table, which has a many-to-one relationship with `Site`. `Site` has a one-to-many relationship with `Patient`.

However, I get a `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "patients" violates foreign key constraint "fk_427e3ubwhw8n7a4id3mmrmjgj"
  Detail: Key (patient_id)=(31) is not present in table "sites".`

I have tried to create a set of patients, add my patient to this set, create a site object, then use this object to set the patients. I am not sure which part of this is going wrong.

```
    Session session = this.getFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;

    try{
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Date parsedDob = Date.valueOf(dob);
        Date parsedDateReg = Date.valueOf(dateReg);

        Site site = new Site();
        site.setSiteId(1);

        IPatient p = new Patient();
        p.setFirstName(firstName);
        p.setLastName(lastName);
        p.setDob(parsedDob);
        p.setDateRegistered(parsedDateReg);
        p.setSite(site);

        Set<IPatient> patientSet = new HashSet<IPatient>();
        patientSet.add(p);

        site.setPatients(patientSet);

        session.save(site);
        session.save(p);
        transaction.commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My Patient.hbm.xml file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.example.model">
<class name="Patient" table="patients">
    <id name="patientId" column="patient_id">
        <generator class="sequence" />
    </id>
    <version name="version" column="version" />
    <property name="firstName" column="first_name" />
    <property name="lastName" column="last_name" />
    <property name="dob" column="dob" />
    <property name="gender" column="gender" />
    <property name="dateRegistered" column="date_registered" />
      <many-to-one name="site" class="com.example.model.Site" not-null="true" />
    <set name="visits" cascade="all">
        <key column="visit_id" />
        <one-to-many class="Visit" />
    </set>
</class>
```

My Site.hmx.xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.example.model">
<class name="Site" table="sites">
    <id name="siteId" column="site_id">
        <generator class="sequence" />
    </id>
    <version name="version" column="version" />
    <property name="name" column="name" />
    <set name="patients" cascade="all">
        <key column="patient_id" />
        <one-to-many class="Patient" />
    </set>
</class>
```

My Patient.java

```java
public class Patient implements IPatient{

    private Integer version;
    private Integer patientId;
    private Set<IVisit> visits;
    private Site site;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dob;
    private Gender gender;
    private Date dateRegistered;

    public Patient(){

    }
}
```

My Site.java

```java
public class Site {

    private Integer siteId;
    private Integer version;
    private Set<IPatient> patients;
    private String name;

    public Site(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line below you should save your site object to db;

```
 site.setSiteId(1);
 session.save(site);
```

After that you can set site object to patient;

```
 p.setSite(site);
```